# Magento 2.3.0 - Multi Website Store URL Return 404 error

Tags: magento2.3, localhost, multi-website, wamp

Workout :

1) Created new folder in Root folder named usa,

2) Copy index.php and .htaccess from root folder and moved to usa folder

3) Created symbolic links to usa folder, usa symbolic links are,

> C:\wamp\www\first_store>mklink /d ..\first_store\usa\app.\app
>   C:\wamp\www\first_store>mklink /d ..\first_store\usa\pub.\pub
>   C:\wamp\www\first_store>mklink /d ..\first_store\usa\lib.\lib
>   C:\wamp\www\first_store>mklink /d ..\first_store\usa\var.\var

4)usa index.php,

Set values for the MAGE_RUN_TYPE and MAGE_RUN_CODE

Open the index.php file under application root directory

```
Replacing this code: $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

by these codes: 

switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/first_store':
        $mageRunCode = 'base';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
    case 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/usa':
        $mageRunCode = 'usa_website';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
}
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $mageRunCode;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $mageRunType;
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

5) usa .htaccess file,

```
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    SetEnvIf Host .*http://127.0.0.1:8080/usa/.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=usa_website
    SetEnvIf Host .*http://127.0.0.1:8080/usa/.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

6) Store configuration,

[image]

7) after run 127.0.0.1:8080/usa return 404 error , how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

1. Check that you have enabled `To include the store code in URLs` as explained in user guide [here](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/store-urls.html).
2. Try to either the `.htaccess` or index.php override. 
   So you can remove, 
   `$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $mageRunCode;
   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $mageRunType;`

   - References:
   - [devdocs.magento.com/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html)
   - [devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html#multi-storecode-baseurl](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html#multi-storecode-baseurl)
   - [docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/store-urls.html](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/store-urls.html)

Comment: After remove $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $mageRunCode;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $mageRunType; still getting same error @Milind Singh

Comment: @zus Have you `included the store code in URLs` from admin config ?

Comment: Also can you add `first_store` in apache conf

Comment: I just want to know how can i add both @Milind Singh

Comment: can you pls join with  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87829/magento-2-3-multi-website-url-return-404-error   @Milind Singh

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Base URL for the store view in the admin. I had the same issue until I did that.

Answer (score 0):

I have setup 2 websites using below steps: (nothing extra)

1. Provide store urls in admin on website level

   > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Base Urls
2. Update `.htaccess` file same as you did in step 5 just exclude protocol and add those lines above `RewriteEnging on` line
3. Update virtual host entry
4. Restart apache

Hope this helps!